# How to remove AccuWeather in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image]

This pop-up window starts to become more and more irritant and I never installed it.

I went to Control Panel to uninstall it but could not see the AccuWeather application in the list.

Could someone share ideas about removing this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not receiving an advertisement from an app, but from Google Chrome.

Open Google Chrome, visit www.accuweather.com and click on the little lock icon in the navigation bar.

At the top it will say: Notifications (allow). Change this to block, and the popups are gone.

***Note***: My chrome is in dutch. I don't know the exact english translation.

Comment: Settings  (you can use address `chrome://settings`) > `Privacy and security` > `Privacy and security` > `Notifications` Remove all unwanted sites in `Allow section`. If you don't have good reason to use Web Notification, consider to block it globally using the switch on top.

Comment: Thanks @Lluser you just missed one step, between "Privacy and security" and "Notifications", there is "Site settings".

Comment: Thanks LPChip, your approach is easier, I will update screenshots to demo how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some details about how to block the notifications:

There are 2 approaches:

1. go to the website which you want to block notifications:
   [image]
2. Go to Chrome settings from address bar

   chrome://settings > Privacy and security > Site settings > Notifications